# What is syntax for two queries in Sequelize?

Tags: angular, sequelize.js

Could someone tell me what is the syntax for using two queries in Sequelize?
I'm trying to do delete from two tables but it's wrong..
I have this code:

```js
defaultAdapter.query('DELETE FROM reasons as r, reason_to_transaction as rt WHERE r.id=:id'
                            'DELETE FROM reason_to_transaction WHERE reason_id=:id', { replacements: objectToSave, type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE }
).then(projects => {
    console.log(projects);
    $scope.editMode = false;
    $scope.activeItem = false;
    $scope.refresh();
});
```

Comment: "but it's wrong"--please show what *did* happen/error logs/etc. It looks like the second query should happen in the `then` clause, and your *existing* `then` should come after that.

Answer (score 0):

It is inappropriate to use two SQL statements within a query.
Each query has a corresponding return value and there is no expected return value for the query above.

how about

```
await defaultAdapter.query("DELETE FROM reasons as r, reason_to_transaction as rt WHERE r.id=:id");
await defaultAdapter.query("DELETE FROM reason_to_transaction WHERE reason_id=:id");
```

Comment: you can find async/await

`let result = await defaultAdapter.query("DELETE FROM reason_to_transaction WHERE reason_id=:id");`

this result is the result of the query execution

Comment: additionally, your code is deleting some data in the database so the result would be the count of the data deleted.

if you want to read data in the database you can use `SELECT STATEMENT`